# Trying to compare the index value of an array of strings to an int value

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to compare the index of the array of strings to a predetermined value so it can return the type of card it will be based on the rank. I know the below method is comparing the actual string to the number I just have no idea how to compare the actual index Value to the number.

```
public String findFaceValue()
{
    String faceValueArray[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"
                              , "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    for(int i = 0; i < faceValueArray.length; ++i)
    {   
        if (faceValueArray[i] == rank)
            return faceValueArray[i];   
    }
    return "Not a valid card";

}
```

Comment: What is `rank`?

Comment: @Meme Lord What do you mean by compare index value of the card. Do you mean the card's individual value, for instance, Ace is highest in rank?

Comment: Okay so `rank` is just any number between 1 and 13 so for example if it's 3 I want the program to return "Three".

Comment: Okay, nevermind I feel like and idiot I could've just returned faceValueArray[rank] THANKS FOR THE HELP ANYWAY GUYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am trying to compare the index of the array of strings to a predetermined value so it can return the type of card it will be based on the rank

If you just want to check whether a given index can get you a valid card. If it does, return the card's name (Rank), else return "Not a valid card". This is what you can do:

```
public String findFaceValue(int index)
{
    String faceValueArray[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
                               "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    if (index < 0 || index >= faceValueArray.length)
        return "Not a valid card";
    return faceValueArray[index];
}
```

> Okay so rank is just any number between 1 and 13 so for example if it's 3 I want the program to return "Three".

To offset the index, just change it to:

```
if (index < 1 || index > faceValueArray.length)
    return "Not a valid card";
return faceValueArray[index-1];
```

Comment: This is exactly it, but I figured it out on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MemeLord Anyway, I will recommend you to set up a class for `Card` and write the attributes in `Card` class instead.

Comment: I have card set up as a class, this is just one part of a much bigger project.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing Strings in Java you need to use `str1.equals(str2)`. In your case (assuming `rank` is a `String`:

```
public String findFaceValue(String rank)
{
    String faceValueArray[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"
                              , "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    for(int i = 0; i < faceValueArray.length; ++i)
    {   
        if (faceValueArray[i].equals(rank))
            return faceValueArray[i];   
    }
    return "Not a valid card";

}
```

If you want to return the card's number value (Ace = 0, Two = 1, ..., Jack = 9, etc.) you could do:

```
public String findFaceValue(int rank)
{
    String faceValueArray[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"
                              , "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};  
    if(rank < faceValueArray.length && rank >= 0)
        return faceValueArray[rank];

    return "Not a valid card";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String Name = // insert code here
int index = -1;
for (int i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++) {
if (arrayName[i].equals(Name)) {
    index = i;
    break;
}
}
```

Also, you can compare with compare to (it compares 2 strings and it returns a number),

```
   String str1 = "String method tutorial";
   String str2 = "compareTo method example";

   int var1 = str1.compareTo( str2 );
   System.out.println("str1 & str2 comparison: "+var1);
```